# Issue with onChange with Safari (desktop and mobile), doesn't seem to fire, but chrome does

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, calculator

So I'm making a calculator, it takes a string, makes an equation, and computers it as you type. Modelled after an app called Soulver.

Live: https://chartley1988.github.io/chartleys-calculator/
Github: https://github.com/chartley1988/chartleys-calculator

This is the part of a react element where it's called:

```
    return (
        <TextareaAutosize
            aria-label='textInput'
            className='editor-input-line'
            id={`input-${lineNumber}`}
            type='text'
            onChange={onChange}
            data-testid="testEditorLine"
        ></TextareaAutosize>
    );
```

It calls a function (which is too long to post) in a parent component. It seems to work perfectly in chrome, but not at all in Safari. What's the best work around for this?

I've tried using an addListener for onChange, instead of directly calling it from Component return. But this seems to only update the answer when focus is removed from the input. And doesn't fix the safari problem. I could maybe just update on any key presses, but with many lines of calculations I feel like this would lead to bad performance.

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved. It ended up being an issue with Regex, NOT onChange as previously thought. Safari does not support lookbehind regex's, which was causing the error. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try use:

```
    return (
        <TextareaAutosize
            aria-label='textInput'
            className='editor-input-line'
            id={`input-${lineNumber}`}
            type='text'
            onChange={() => onChange()}
            data-testid="testEditorLine"
        ></TextareaAutosize>
    );
```